# Integrability of $\int_{\mathbb{R}} 1/(1+|x|)^p d\mathcal{L}(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $p>0$. For which $p$ is the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{(1+|x|)^p} d\mathcal{L}(x)$ finite?

I assume $f(x)= \frac{1}{(1+|x|)^p}$ is integrable for $p>1$, but how exactly can I show this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following: split the integral al $2$ then

\begin{align*}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{(1+|x|)^p}\,d\mathcal{L}&=2\left( \int_{0}^2\frac{1}{(1+x)^p}\,d\mathcal{L}+ \int_{2}^\infty\frac{1}{(1+x)^p}\,d\mathcal{L}\right)\\
&=2\left( \int_{0}^2\frac{1}{(1+x)^p}\,d\mathcal{L}+ \int_{\color{red}3}^\infty\frac{1}{x^p}\,d\mathcal{L}\right).\end{align*}
The first integral is finite and smaller than $2$ and the convergence of the second depends on $p$ as you said, but the antiderivative is now easy to compute.

---

Previous reasoning:

- For $|x|\leq c$ (c any constant) the integrand is finite so the intergral cannot diverge.
- For $|x|\gg 1$ $\frac{1}{(1+|x|)^p}\approx \frac{1}{|x|^p}$ which is easy to integrate.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a similar way to solve this for $f(x)=\frac{1}{(1+|x|^2)^p}$?

Comment: Similar yes, but not exactly the same. Shifting the integral as I did won't result in such a nice result due to mixed terms appearing due to the square. Nonetheless, for $x\geq 1$ you can obviously bound the term by above, using
$$\frac{1}{(1+|x|^q)^p}\leq \frac{1}{(|x|^q)^p}$$
but you can also bound it from below, using
$$\frac{1}{(1+|x|^q)^p}\geq \frac{1}{(|x+1|^q)^p}$$ from which you can then perform a simple shift in the integral bounds to get the result